# How to proof $\int_{(0,\infty)} \int_{(0,\infty)} |\sin x| \,\, e^{-xy} \,\, dx \,\, dy < \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

How can I proof this?

$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty |\sin x| \,\, e^{-xy} \,\, dx \,\, dy < \infty$

---

I tried to say $\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty |\sin x| \,\, e^{-xy} \,\, dx \,\, dy \leq \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-xy} \,\, dx \,\, dy$ but that didn't help since the right side is $\infty$.
All other ideas failed as well.

---

My "main idea" was to use Tonelli Fubini:

$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty |\sin x| \,\, e^{-xy} \,\, dy \,\,dx = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} |\sin(x)| \,\,dx$

But I don't know how to continue here now. I tried again to say $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} |\sin(x)| \,\,dx \leq \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x} \,\,dx$ but the right side is $\infty$ again.

For Tonelli it would be also enough to check $\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty |\sin x| \,\, e^{-xy} \,\, dx \,\,dy$ about finity, but here I get no better result.

Comment: You need to show your attempt otherwise the post will be deleted

Comment: "All other ideas" - what are those? A hint to try something more useful: write$$\int_0^\infty e^{-xy}|\sin x|dx=\sum_{n\ge0}\Im\left(\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}e^{-x(y-i)}dx-\int_{(n+1)\pi}^{(n+2)\pi}e^{-x(y-i)}dx\right).$$

Comment: What is that big $I$ before the brackets? I don't think we've had to notation

Comment: @LukasNiessen It means "imaginary part".

Comment: @K.defaoite is right. You might have instead seen $\operatorname{Im}$.

Comment: Ah okay, sure I know the other notation. I have updated the question with my "main approach". I think we shall somehow use Fubini / Tonelli because that's the topic of this exercise sheet

Comment: @LukasNiessen The divergence of $\int_0^{\infty}|\sin x|/x\,dx$ is well known. You might want to search for that problem on here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the function $(x,y)\mapsto\left|\sin x\right|e^{-xy}$ is
non-negative and measurable, so Tonelli Theorem is applicable. We
have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left|\sin x\right|e^{-xy}dydx\\
 & = & \int_{0}^{\infty}\left|\sin x\right|\left(-\frac{1}{x}e^{-xy}\mid_{y=0}^{y=\infty}\right)dx\\
 & = & \int_{0}^{\infty}\left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|dx\\
 & = & \infty.
\end{eqnarray*}
To prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|dx=\infty$,
we note that $|\sin x|\geq\frac{1}{2}$ for $x\in[2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{6},2n\pi+\frac{5\pi}{6}]$.
Therefore,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|dx & \geq & \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{6}}^{2n\pi+\frac{5\pi}{6}}\left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|dx\\
 & \geq & \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2n\pi+\frac{5\pi}{6}}\cdot(\frac{2\pi}{3})\\
 & = & \infty.
\end{eqnarray*}
It is impossible to prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left|\sin x\right|e^{-xy}dydx<\infty$.
Is there any typo ?